# Dimensionality reduction with b-splines - conceptual question

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction, splines

In this R code:

```
# `data` is say 1000 x 50 data matrix
require(fda)
n = 1000  # no of observations
k = 5    # reduced dimensionality
x = seq(0, 1, length.out = n)
splinebasis_B = create.bspline.basis(c(0, 1), k)
base_B = eval.basis(x, splinebasis_B)
data_reduced = data %*% base_B
```

as I understand, the last operation does not **project** (or otherwise reducingly transform)  `data` just yet, but rather it gives us `data_reduced` on which we can run some fitting algos (regressions, trees etc.).

For this reason, we cannot claim that `data_reduced` is compressed version of `data`.

Is this correct? Am I missing anything? What's the right way to think about `data_reduced`? It's clearly mapped to a lower-dimensional space, and there is loss as `data`'s variance got collapsed during the multiplication with fewer columns... but I feel like somehow `data_reduced` is not "optimal". It's not the best representation of `data` in `k`-dimensional space... What is it then?

Appreciate your help.

For background, I'm talking specifically about using splines for dimensionality reduction, in particular as applied to functional data (screenshot)

.[image]

Answer (score 2):

B-splines can be used to approximate a 1D curve.

Thus, if you have a set of points $(x,y)$, you can approximate the non-linear relation between $x$ and $y$ by first expanding x into a B-spline basis and then fitting the expanded basis to $y$ using a standard linear model such as linear regression.

So now if you wanted to reduce the dimensionality of several sets of $(x,y)$ pairs, you first do a basis expansion of all the $x$'s and then for each set, fit the B-spline expansion to the paired $y$'s. Then, the fitted coefficients from each $(x,y)$ set can be seen as a reduced rank approximation of the original $(x,y)$ set.

**Note that it is vitally important that each $x$ be expanded at the same knot locations with the same degrees of freedom, otherwise comparing fitted coefficients becomes an apples to oranges comparison.**

Comment: thank you for the response, I clarified the context.

Comment: thanks a lot, Cliff. Any change you could elaborate. What exactly is the operation for 'basis expansion of all the $x$'s? Is `data_reduced` matrix from the snippet such expanded version of $\boldsymbol X$?